# Python IO: adding characters to filename during open()

Tags: python, file-io, ftp, io

I'm writing a data scraper for the NHANES data sets from the CDC. I'm having trouble with the file IO.

Given a year, group, and title (e.g. 2000, "exam", "Audiometry"), I create the filename string:

```
filename = "nhanes."+str(year)+"-"+str(year+1)+"."+group+"."+titles[i]+".xpt"
```

This successfully prints out as

```
"nhanes.2000-2001.exam.Audiometry.xpt"
```

I then download the .xpt file over an ftp server using this code:

```
req = urllib2.Request(ftp_loc)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
xpt_data = response.read()
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write(xpt_data)
f.close()
```

**ftp_loc** is something like "ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/nhanes/2001-2002/OHXPRL_B.xpt"

Then, problems: I get the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  (... method stack here ...)
IOError:[Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'nhanes.2000-2001.exam.Audiometry\r.xpt'
```

As you can see, the filename now has a "\r" in it :( Any ideas on how it got there? Thank you!! ~Emily

Comment: Rather than using `print` to check your string, use `repr()`. I bet you the `\r` will show up.

Answer (score 2):

The `\r` in the filename probably got there because it was already there in the data you create the filename from. In particular `titles[i]`. If you show us the code that populates that array we may be able to provide a better solution.

A workaround in the meantime is the following:

```
filename = "nhanes.%d-%d.%s.%s.xpt" % (year, year+1, group titles[i].strip())
```

The actual solution to your issue is calling the `strip` method of the string that will get rid of the carriage return character (that is what the `\r` is called). Note that the `strip` method will also get rid of other characters ([whitespace mostly](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)).

The other changes to the code is just - in my opinion - a better way to write the same thing you wrote. Instead of concatenating substrings you actually use the builtin [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) to create the filename. The end result should be the same.

Comment: Your answer trumps my quickly-written-on-the-train one, most definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the contents of the year, group and title lists coming from?  \r is a carriage-return character, so I'd suggest you sanitize them to ensure you remove all such characters, either when you populate the lists, or when you use them.

```
filename = "nhanes."+str(year)+"-"+str(year+1)+"."+group+"."+titles[i].strip("\r")+".xpt"
```